# Display DIV based on conditions of 2 dropdowns selection using HTML & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My question is to populate DIV based on conditions of **2 dropdowns selection** using HTML & Javascript:

I have 2 dropdown

1st dropdown contains manager id 2nd dropdown contains Yes/No

After selecting 2 dropdowns (Either "A"/"B"/"C" from first dropdown & Yes from second dropdown) then div which contains one text box and submit button should be displayed else it should be hidden.

Below is the code I tried and it didn't give the expected result.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#manager").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "A" || ($(this).val() == "B") || ($(this).val() == "C") ) && $("#area").val() == "Y") {
      $("#countryname").show();
      $("#sub").show();
    } else {
      $("#countryname").hide();
      $("#sub").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Select Manager</span>
<select id="manager">
  <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
  <option value="A">ABC</option>
  <option value="B">BCD</option>
  <option value="C">CDE</option>
  <option value="D">DEF</option>
</select>
<hr />
<span>Is selected area covered?</span>
<select id="area">
  <option value="N">No</option>
  <option value="Y">Yes</option>
</select>
<hr />
<div id="country" style="display: none">
  Label:
  <input type="text" id="countryname" />
  <input type="submit" id="sub">
</div>
```

Comment: The four possible values are A, B, C and D, but you're comparing the value against two letter country codes?

Comment: Syntax error in the condition. Also note that you don't need all that parens; you can do `if (a == 1 || a == 2 || a == 3)`. And && is evaluated before || so you might want to also check the parens with regard to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here's what you're looking for,

JS

```
$(()=>{
$("#area").change((e)=>{
    if(($("#manager").val() == "A" || $("#manager").val() == "B" || $("#manager").val() == "C" || $("#manager").val() == "D") && $("#area").val() == "Y"){
        $("#country").show();
    }
    else{
        alert("You choose no!!");
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
})
```